# How to combine multiple urls into a single websocket?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am trying to send multiple urls to the server using a single websocket ? How do i do that?

Comment: Please try to add the code which you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do it by putting the URLs into some type of object, JSON encoding that object and then sending the JSON string.

**Send JSON encoded array:**

```
socket.send(JSON.stringify([url1, url2, url3]));
```

or

```
socket.send(JSON.stringify({
     msgType: "urlList",
     data: [url1, url2, url3]
}));
```

**Send JSON encoded object with URLs as properties:**

```
socket.send(JSON.stringify({
    msgType: "urlList", 
    url1: someUrl1, 
    url2: someURL2, 
    url3: someURL3
}));
```

The `msgType` property is just assuming that you want some structure to your messages so that the server knows what you are sending.  It is not required.

Comment: Thank u @jfriend00 can u please send both server and client code using the above snippet . Sorry I am really n ew to this

Comment: @Viveksc - That isn't how stackoverflow works.  You ask a question, we try to answer it for you.  You learn from that and write your own code.  We don't just write your code for you.  You asked how to send multiple URLs using a webSocket and I answered that.  If you don't understand something about the answer, then ask for clarification about something that I wrote.

Comment: Sorry I am new to  Stack overflow also . Thank u for ur feedback

Comment: @Viveksc - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.